# is line folded? - How to check for folds in VIM

Tags: function, vim, folding

I'm writing some folding functions and I am at a point where I need to check if the current line is actually a fold.

The reason for this is because it is a custom fold method that depends on searching/matching certain lines.

For example, if the current line is folded and looks like:

```
-FOO------------------------
```

If you do something like:

```
getline('.')
```

You would basically get `FOO` so there is no way (that I know of) to know if I am at a fold or not.

Is there a helper function for this?

I would think it would have to be something like:

```
is_folded('.')
```

I could probably mess with the `foldtext` to assign a special title for the fold but I want to avoid this.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

From `:help eval.txt`

> foldclosed({lnum})
>
> The result is a Number.  If the line {lnum} is in a closed
>   fold, the result is the number of the first line in that fold.
>   If the line {lnum} is not in a closed fold, -1 is returned.

You can check for a given line if it returns -1 or a line number, you can probably implement your `isfolded()` function this way.

If you are looking for Vim script function or feature , it is a good idea to start by searching in `eval.txt` which contains lots of relevant information.

Comment: Absolutely correct. Most of the times I marvel at VIM docs (:help foo) but in cases like this - where I'm not sure how to search for it) it sucks. Thanks for the quick response!

Comment: @alfredodeza : I am not a Vim script expert, but I got the feeling that most (if not all?) of the syntax and functions are available from `eval.txt`. So in doubt you might want to start looking in that (very long) help file and do a quick search on your problem. That's what I did to answer your question.